# Sonarqube: Error occurred while querying the server version in Gitlab-CI

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, sonarqube, .net-6.0, sonarqube-scan

I have a Sonarqube deployment running on Tanzu Kubernetes. For this Sonarqube deployment I have setup a Gitlab-CI pipeline to run a sonar-scan on a .Net 6 API.

When I execute the GitlabCI pipeline I am getting an error :

```
$ cd /root/.dotnet/tools
$ ./dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"gl" /d:sonar.login="$SONAR_TOKEN" /d:"sonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL"
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.13
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
12:06:38.194  Updating build integration targets...
12:06:38.428  Downloading from http://XX.X.XX.XX:9000/api/server/version failed. Http status code is Forbidden.
12:06:38.431  An error occured while querying the server version! Please check if the server is running and if the address is correct.
12:06:38.434  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

The GitlabCI pipeline is as below:

```
before_script:


- 'dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'

build_job:
  tags:
    - orion
  only:
    - sonarqube
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

publish_job:
  tags:
    - orion
  only:
    - sonarqube
  stage: publish
  artifacts:
      name: "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
      paths:
        - ./$PUBLISH_DIR
  script:
    - dotnet publish ./src --configuration Release --output $(pwd)/$PUBLISH_DIR

analyze_job:
  tags:
    - orion
  only:
    - sonarqube
  stage: analyze
  image:
    name: golide/net6-sonar:0.1.1
  variables:
    # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: 0
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - "cd /root/.dotnet/tools"
    - "./dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:\"gl\" /d:sonar.login=\"$SONAR_TOKEN\" /d:\"sonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL\" "
    - "dotnet build"
    - "./dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=\"$SONAR_TOKEN\""
  allow_failure: true
```

I am using a custom .Net 6 image (golide/net6-sonar:0.1.1) with sonar tooling as follows :

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
    RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
    RUN echo $PATH
    RUN export ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
    RUN echo $PATH
```

The Sonarqube instance is already accessible from the rest of the internet (exposed via Kubernetes LoadBalancer service) and it is on the same network as the GitlabCI server.

What I have done:

1. Configured SONAR_TOKEN in the GitLab CI pipeline project
2. Configured SONAR_HOST_URL in the GitLab CI pipeline project
3. Configured sonar-project.properties in my project as below :

```
    sonar.projectKey=my_oasys
    sonar.projectName=oasys
    sonar.projectVersion=1.0
    
    # Comma-separated paths to directories containing the source code (required)
    sonar.sources=.
    
    # Language and plugin settings
    sonar.language=cs
    sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPathsEnabled=true
    
    # Encoding of the source files
    sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
    
    # Analysis exclusions (optional)
    sonar.exclusions=**/bin/**/*, **/obj/**/*
    
    # Test exclusions (optional)
    sonar.test.exclusions=**/*Test.cs
    
    # SonarQube server URL (adjust as per your setup)
    sonar.host.url=http://xx.x.xx.xx:9000
```

VERSIONS
Sonarqube version - Version 7.1.0.11001
Postgres version - 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1)

What am I missing ?